# Cannot ping external server within traefik

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

Due to a problem with my internet provider, I had to move many of my running services from my local NAS to a vServer at IONOS. Everything is running in Docker. I am using Traefik as a reverse proxy. My problem is that I still need to run a few services on my NAS. The NAS is accessible via an IPv6 address. Of course I want to make this accessible via Traefik as well. When I run Traefik in network mode bridge, the redirects don't work (error: '502 Bad Gateway' caused by: dial tcp [:::::]:00000: connect: cannot assign requested address). But as soon as I give Traefik the network mode host, everything works.

Is there a way to give Traefik in network mode bridge or does it really only work like this?

- Docker-Compose file

  ```yaml
  version: "3"

  services:
      proxy:
          image: 'traefik:latest'
          container_name: 'proxy'
          restart: on-failure
          ports:
              - 80:80/tcp
              - 443:443/tcp
          volumes:
              - ./config/certs:/certs:ro
              - ./config/traefik/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
              - ./config/traefik/dyn.yml:/dynconf/dyn.yml
              - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
          labels:
              - traefik.enable=true
              - traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.domain.com`)
              - traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal
              - traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
              - traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=https
              - traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls=true
              - traefik.http.routers.traefik_https.middlewares=basic-auth-global
              - traefik.http.middlewares.basic-auth-global.basicauth.users=SECURE
  ```
- Traefik Configuration

  ```yaml
  api:
    insecure: false
    dashboard: true
  serverstransport:
    insecureskipverify: true
  providers:
    docker:
      endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
      watch: true
      exposedbydefault: false
    file:
      directory: /dynconf
      watch: true
  entryPoints:
    http:
      address: ":80"
      http:
        redirections:
          entrypoint:
            to: "https"
            scheme: "https"
    https:
      address: ":443"
  ```
- Dynamic Configuration for Traefik

  ```yaml
  http:
    middlewares:
      https-redirect:
        redirectScheme:
          scheme: "https"
    routers:
      service1:
        entryPoints:
          - "http"
          - "https"
        rule: "Host(`service1.domain.com`)"
        service: "cervice1-redirect"
        tls: {}
      service2:
        entryPoints:
          - "http"
          - "https"
        rule: "Host(`service2.domain.com`)"
        service: "service2-redirect"
        tls: {}
      service3:
        entryPoints:
          - "http"
          - "https"
        rule: "Host(`service3.domain.com`)"
        service: "service3-redirect"
        tls: {}
    services:
      service1-redirect:
        loadBalancer:
          servers:
            - url: "https://[xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx]"
          passHostHeader: true
      service2-redirect:
        loadBalancer:
          servers:
            - url: "https://[xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx]"
          passHostHeader: true
      service3-redirect:
        loadBalancer:
          servers:
            - url: "https://[xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx]"
          passHostHeader: true
  tls:
    certificates:
      - certFile: "ssl-cert1.cer"
        keyfile: "privkey1.key"
        stores:
          - default
      - certFile: "ssl-cert2.cer"
        keyFile: "privkey2.key"
    stores:
      default:
        defaultCertificate:
          certFile: "ssl-cert1.cer"
          keyFile: "privkey1.key"
  ```